# YUI nested selectors

Tags: javascript, yui

I am a YUI(AUI) beginner. In jQuery I would do

```
$(image).find(selector).text();
```

How can this be achieved in YUI?

```
AUI().use('event', 'node', function(A) { 

var subImages = A.all('.sub_image_conatiner');
for (var i = 0; i < subImages.size(); i++){

    var image = subImages.get(i);
    //get child elements of image here
}   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought `Y.all(foo).all(selector).get('text')` would just work but it unfortunately doesn't.

I'd recommend that you use only one selector to match the sub elements:

```
Y.all('.parent-class .child-class').get('text');
```

If you can't, then you don't have to iterate through the nodes like a normal JS array. You can use `.each()`.

```
var texts = [];
Y.all(foo).each(function (node, i) {
  texts = texts.concat(node.all(bar).get('text'));
});
console.log(texts);
```

I'll file a bug with YUI to see if it makes sense to add `Y.NodeList.prototype.all`